# deleteFile endpoint script not being accessed

Tags: php, fine-uploader

I am using FineUploader 3.5 on a test website (Win7 xampp/apache server)

My images can be Drag N Dropped and upload to my upload directory just fine.
When I click on the delete link I deletes the file in the file list but not the actual file in the upload folder also the image remains. I have set the endpoint in the deleteFile: but it never seems to execute it.

```
        function createImageUploaders() {
    var freeimagesuploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    // Pass the HTML element here
        element: document.getElementById('free-images-uploader'),
    // or, if using jQuery
    // element: $('#free-images-uploader')[0],
    // Use the relevant server script url here
    // if it's different from the default “/server/upload”
    request: {
                endpoint: '<?php echo $baseurl?>components/com_classifiedsredux/library/uploader.php'
            },
            multiple: true,
            validation: {
                allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
                //sizeLimit: 204800, // 200 kB = 200 * 1024 bytes
                sizeLimit: 5120000, // 5 mb or 5000 kB = 5000 * 1024 bytes
                itemLimit: 3
            },
            text: {
                uploadButton: "<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class='icon-upload icon-white'></i> Click or Drag n' Drop images to upload&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>",
                dragZone: 'Drop images here to upload',
              },
            deleteFile: {
                enabled: true,
                forceConfirm: true,
                    endpoint: '$this->baseurl' + 'components/com_classifiedsredux/library/deletefile.php'
              },
            failedUploadTextDisplay: {
                mode: 'custom',
                maxChars: 40,
                responseProperty: 'error',
                enableTooltip: true
            },
            debug: true,
            callbacks: {
                onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
                    if (responseJSON.success) {
                        $('#free-images-uploader').append('<img src="<?php echo $baseurl?>images/com_classifiedsredux/ads/originals/' + fileName + '" alt="' + fileName + '" style="height:60px; display:inline">&nbsp;');
                    }
                },
                onDeleteComplete: function(id) {
                //  if (responseJSON.success) {
                        $('#free-images-uploader').append(id + '&nbsp;dropped');
                //  }
                }
            }
        });
```

Here is the webconsole log, I Drag n Drop 3 images:

> ```
>     [08:40:27.642] [FineUploader] Grabbed 3 dropped files.
>     [08:40:27.643] [FineUploader] Processing 3 files or inputs...
>     [08:40:27.647] [FineUploader] Sending upload request for 0
>     [08:40:27.649] [FineUploader] Sending upload request for 1
>     [08:40:27.652] [FineUploader] Sending upload request for 2
>     [08:40:27.795] POST http  :  //j3demo/components/com_classifiedsredux/library/uploader.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 20ms]
>     [08:40:27.796] POST http  :  //j3demo/components/com_classifiedsredux/library/uploader.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 59ms]
>     [08:40:27.797] POST http  :  //j3demo/components/com_classifiedsredux/library/uploader.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 61ms]
>     [08:40:27.858] GET http  :  //j3demo/components/com_classifiedsredux/images/loading.gif [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 41ms]
>     [08:40:27.777] [FineUploader] xhr - server response received for 0
>     [08:40:27.777] [FineUploader] responseText = {"success":true,"uploadName":"AD2-365.jpg"}
>     [08:40:27.789] [FineUploader] xhr - server response received for 2
>     [08:40:27.789] [FineUploader] responseText = {"success":true,"uploadName":"eibAD4-783.gif"}
>     [08:40:27.803] [FineUploader] xhr - server response received for 1
>     [08:40:27.803] [FineUploader] responseText = {"success":true,"uploadName":"AD3-433.gif"}
>     [08:40:27.953] GET http  :  //j3demo/images/com_classifiedsredux/ads/originals/AD2.jpg [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 4ms]
>     [08:40:27.956] GET http  :  //j3demo/images/com_classifiedsredux/ads/originals/eibAD4.gif [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 3ms]
>     [08:40:27.958] GET http  :  //j3demo/images/com_classifiedsredux/ads/originals/AD3.gif [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 5ms]
> ```

, then I delete the 2nd one:

```
   [08:40:34.000] [FineUploader] Sending DELETE request for 1
    [08:40:34.001] [FineUploader] Submitted delete file request for 1
    [08:40:34.140] DELETE http  :  //j3demo/components/com_classifiedsredux/library/deletefile.php/0cc36f82-5684-4b37-b0f9-6a065ace91b4? [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 11ms]
    [08:40:34.075] [FineUploader] Delete request for 'AD3.gif' has succeeded.
```

Comment: The file in the list is only removed if the associated ajax call returns a 200, 202, or 204 status in the response.  So, the delete request is apparently reaching your server, and your server is apparently responding positively.  Please show the DELETE request (headers and payload) along with the headers and payload of the associated response.  You can do this using Chrome's network tab, for example.

Comment: I found the deleteFile endpoint option was incorrect it should be: endpoint: '<?php echo $baseurl?>components/com_classifiedsredux/library/deletefile.php'

Comment: I use Firefox.  It does get to my deletefile script, but no items when I dump $_POST to a debug file My script returns 200 (even thou the server always seemed to return 200 even when it didn't find my script, like it didn't care??

Comment: I'm not sure what specific problem you are having right now.  It sounds like you need to spend some time working out the issues with your server side code and environment.

Comment: my server side script (deletefile.php) is getting accessed but I am not getting any info other than the UUID at the moment I am just returning 200  but if I change that to anything else (say 404) it doesn't make any difference.  How do I access the filename that is to be removed from my uploaded folder?

Comment: I still don't really understand your question. You must have a map, server-side, of files to UUIDs.  If you have this map, removing files is easy.  Have a look at my blog post which explains the feature at a high-level.  http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/01/delete-uploaded-file-in-33.html

Comment: So you are stating that for every file/image uploaded I will get a UUID and should save a table/file that holds the UUID and its corresponding filename. Then use this to obtain the filename and delete it from the folder

Comment: Thank you for your responses and patience. I set up the table and it works very nicely.  Perhaps the following should be another post, I am displaying the thumbnails of the uploaded images, but how can I delete the thumbnail displays when I delete the file itself? Is there an unappend I can perform with the onDeleteComplete callback? I would think it might be easier to attach it to the right of the file name/size/delete link. Then when the list item is removed, the image is also.

Comment: Please create a new question for this.